# Printing an array in Codeiginter view page

Tags: php, arrays, view

**My Controller is:**

```
$time=$this->input->post('time');
       $data['list']=array(
        'id'=>NULL,
                  'waytype'=>$this->input->post('waytype'),
        'form'=>$this->input->post('from'),
        'to'=>$this->input->post('to'),
        'date'=>$this->input->post('date'),
        'time'=>$this->input->post('time'),

        );
    $this->load->view('search/index',$data);
```

**In view searc/index**
      `print_r('list')` **is working fine**

> Array ( [id] => [waytype] => oneway [form] => Bhubaneswar [to] =>
>   Sambalapur [date]   => 12/10/2014 [time] => PM )

**I want to print it name wise i.e list[from],list[to]
 etc but it is showing error.
I am confused how to use for each here**

Comment: where are the codes of your view file? you should also add it inside your question, so that we see how you are using your array.

Comment: Also it would be useful to see what kind of error the view is throwing.

Comment: If the error message bothers you, just switch off your screen. If you want help in fixing it, then share the error with us, as well as the code that produces it.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `foreach` loop.

```
if (! empty($list)) {
  foreach ($list as $k => $v) {
    echo "<br/>".$k . ' => ' . $v;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print data you can use like this

```
foreach($list as $list =>ll):
       echo $ll->id;
       echo $ll->waytype;
       echo$ll->form;
end_foreach;
```

to print the array like this